# Pip installation failure using python3 on linux ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have installed the python3 from source
Python 3.7.4

I am trying to install the pip, with following failure any idea on this will be very useful.

curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

sudo python3 get-pip.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 22711, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 198, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as pip_entry_point
.
.
.
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/tmp/tmp7grgb9bt/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 92, in <module>
RuntimeError: Python 3.5 or later is required
```

$> python3 -V

```
Python 3.7.4
```

Comment: `sudo python3 --version` ? Compare `echo $PATH`  and `sudo sh -c 'echo $PATH'`

Comment: Yes you are right /usr/local/bin not present in sudo -c 'echo $PATH'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to `$PATH` issue `sudo python3` runs a different Python compared to `python3`. Add `/usr/local/bin` to `PATH` in `/root/.bash_profile`. Or simply run with full path:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/python3 get-pip.py
```